# Render a template and send_from_directory at the same time flask

Tags: python, flask

I need to render a template and dynamically load a graph  my problem is that if I have the same request name twice but a different graph it always displays the same graph as the render_template and send_from_file are in different routes even though in the saved directory the graph is updated.

Heres the line for rendering the template

```
return render_template("graph.html",figName=("averageComments.png"),title="Average Comments for top 500 users")

img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=figName) }}
```

in the  html it shows the right image name but the wrong outdated image like if I click on the url it will show the correct image.

I need this to somehow update the route by calling send_from_file before calling render_template is there anyway I can do this

If I cannot do this this way please recommend  another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even though in the actual directory the file is updated

If it is the case that you've updated or rewritten the file, then it's possible your browser is caching the old version. I would try clearing the browser cache (Shift + F5 in Chrome) and seeing if that updates the figure.

In general, I think that "static" (not changing) is a bad place to put user-generated content, for this exact reason.